# Wordpress: unwanted articles and categories created automatically

Tags: wordpress

In my Wordpress control panel, under the menu Articles and Categories, there are a lot of strange items created automatically.
Anyone could explain me why? It's an hacker attack to my wordpress site? Or maybe could be a plugin?
Thanks

[image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks, like you have unwanted guest. First check your password and change it to a secure one, also think about 2F authentication.
Check if there are any new users with privileges other than intended (the ones you have created).
All new user roles should be set to subscriber, unless you need to change it.

Comment: Solved by changing the password! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please go to settings>general and check if the new user role is anything other than subscriber. If this happens to be the case, you should go to the users tab as well and delete or change privileges to the accounts.